# Equivalence of sequence approximation and sum decomposition definition of Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, lp-spaces, fourier-transform

Let $1<p<2$ . Let us denote$L^p(\mathbb R^n)$ by $L^p$ in short and let $1/p+1/p'=1$ . Let $f \in L^p$ , let $g_n$ be a sequence in $C_c(\mathbb R^n)$ converging to $f$ in $L^p$ . Let $g$ be the $L^{p'}$ limit of $\hat g_n$ in $L^{p'}$ . Let  $f_1 =f.1_{\{|f(x)|\le1\}}\in L^2$ and $f_2=f.1_{\{|f(x)|\ge1\}}\in L^1$

Then how to show that $g=\hat f_1+\hat f_2$ ?

I can show that it is enough to check for one sequence in $C_c$ converging to $f$ in $L^p$ i.e. that if two sequences in $C_c$ converges to $f$ in $L^p$ , then their Fourier transforms converges to the same function in $L^{p'}$. But I don't know if it is helpful.

Please help.

Comment: Hint: How do you know that $\hat g_n$ _has_ a limit in $L^{p'}$? (The proof of that fact shows that actually $g=\hat f$. But $f=f_1+f_2$.)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich : $\hat g_n$ has a limit in $L^{p'} $ as it is Cauchy there due to inequality $||\hat g ||_{p'}\le ||g||_p$ for $C_c$ functions .  I do not a priori  know the limit is $\hat f $ , it is defined in that way provided we can show the limit is $\hat f _1 + \hat f_2$ as stated ...

Comment: Right. So $||\hat g_n-\hat f||_{p'} <= c||g_n-f||_p\to0$. So $g=\hat f$.